# Как определить номер недели по дате?

Tags: c++

Как определить номер недели по текущей дате на c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстренько накидал, если какеие-то функции не понятны, погугли, на руском сегменте есть хорошие объяснения.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t rowTime = time(0);
    tm *ptm = localtime(&rowTime);
    ptm->tm_year = 2018 - 1900;

    std::cout << "Enter date and month: ";

    std::cin >> ptm->tm_mday >> ptm->tm_mon;// ввод дня и месяца
    ptm->tm_mon -= 1;
    mktime(ptm);
    
    int wNum = (ptm->tm_yday + 1) / 7;
    if ((ptm->tm_yday + 1) % 7) ++wNum;
    std::cout << wNum << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Посчитай количество дней от даты, с которой начинаешь отсчёт недель, например пусть это будет days. А затем просто сделай так: days % 7. Получишь количество недель с начальной даты по сегодняшнюю. Опционально можно добавить условие, которое будет прибавлять/вычитать одну неделю, если дата выпадает на середину недели

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я по началу так и сделал, но потом узнал про структуру, содержащую календарную дату и время с разбивкой на компоненты, и по итоги написал простенькую функцию:
```int week_num(int day, int mon, int year)
{
    struct tm tm;
    char timebuf[64];

    // Обнуляем структуру
    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof tm);

    tm.tm_mday = day;
    tm.tm_mon = mon;
    tm.tm_year = year;

    // Вызываем mktime to recompute tm.tm_wday and tm.tm_yday
    mktime(&tm);

    if (strftime(timebuf, sizeof timebuf, "%W", &tm) != 0) {
    }
    return stoi(timebuf);
}```